# SearchAdRequest does not work with AdMobAdsSDK6.2.1

Tags: android, admob

I am unable to understand why searchAdRequest API does not work - my application returns a null pointer exception.Is it because I am not registered?. somewhere I read that SearchAdRequest is by invitation only. Now the problem is that how do I try it out to determine if it is what I want?.

also a related question, if I want to register for getting access to it,  how do I find the url of my app?. I have not registered it in google playstore yet. Though I have it registered in google cloud services - I am little confused here. any help will be appreciated.

I got the answer to my question.
Null reference because i was not inflating the parent resource. 
Also, with regard to app registering. I got the details from another post on the same subject. 
thanks to everyone for helping out.

Comment: Provide some code and link to what you mean by SearchAdRequest

Comment: Thanks William for responding. It looks like I need to register with AdMob with my mobile app URL. Thanks to some previous post on this same subject in stackoverflow I did that. Now I am waiting for the response from google.